# Trying to create a looping bootstrap cards in php

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

im fairly new in php and mysqli and trying to make some basic website.

basically i want to make a looping statement in php to create cards in the same row with same size and col without myself creating the cards manually in html.

using bootstrap, php and mysqli

the database that i use contains itemname(varchar),itemprice(varchar), and itemimage(mediumblob)

the code is successfully running, but the output doesnt match the bootstrap cards, and they refuse to be in the same row

can anyone help me ?
thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<?php

require 'dbh.inc.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM item";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

 if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)) {
  echo "error";
 } else{
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    print '<div class="row">';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      print' <div class="col-4">';
      print'    <div class="card">';
      print'     <img height="250" width="250" class="card-img-top" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['itemimage'] ).'">';
      print'      <div class="card-body">';
      print'       <h5 class="card-title">'.$row["itemname"].'</h5>';
      print'       <p class="card-text">Price : '.$row["itemprice"].'</p>';
      print'      </div>';
      print'    </div>';
      print'   </div>';
    } 
   } else {
    print' </div>';
    }
  }
$conn->close();
?>

 <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap/js/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-7aThvCh9TypR7fIc2HV4O/nFMVCBwyIUKL8XCtKE+8xgCgl/PQGuFsvShjr74PBp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wR8C.png)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you tried checking the expected output, matching it against your PHP code, and see what is missing - cause we can't guess that

Comment: i tried to "manuallly" create the cards in html/css without using database incase my html syntax is wrong. after the output is suit my desire, i tried to create the loop to extracting variables and images from the mysql database and implement it to html. and it succeed to read the database, table and the content. but the result are not right. i did upload the output in my question. you can check it out

Comment: Well, you have not provided the expected markup structure. Additionally, have you tried to compare the **current** markup with the **expected** one?

Comment: solved, i forgot to change the bootstrap directory in this php file...
sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going on the assumption you've tested that there actually is data in your query result.

Copied and updated your code a bit. Few things:

- You close a div (for the row) in the `else` of the `if()` statement, but you open it in the `if()` side.
- You could close PHP and use plain HTML within functions/loops, so long as you properly use `<?php` or `<?=` and `?>`

---

```
<?php function createCard(array $row) { ?>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
            <img height="250"
                 width="250"
                 class="card-img-top"
                 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode($row['itemimage']) ?>">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><?= $row["itemname"] ?></h5>
                <p class="card-text">Price : <?= $row["itemprice"] ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <?php

        require 'dbh.inc.php';

        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM item";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            echo "error";
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    createCard($row);
                }
            }
        }
        $conn->close();
        ?>
        </div>

        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-7aThvCh9TypR7fIc2HV4O/nFMVCBwyIUKL8XCtKE+8xgCgl/PQGuFsvShjr74PBp"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```